# Branch deeplink does not pass the parameters to Android app when the app is installed for first time

Tags: branch.io

The user clicks on the deeplink and is redirected to the google play store to install the application. When the installation is completed, the application is opened but the deeplink parameters are not passed.

If the user clicks again on the deeplink with the application installed, then the parameters are passed correctly to the application.

The behavior has been changed from last week.

Have you noticed any similar behavior?

Comment: Can you share more details like SDK version, Manifest.xml file and code snippets of Branch SDK initalization?